# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_SDL_Init"

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, sdl-2, undefined-symbol

Every time I try and compile a program that uses SDL, it gives me a

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/testProgram
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/testProgram build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Window.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o -L/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework -L/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      Window::startWindow() in Window.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      Window::exitWindow(bool) in Window.o
  "_SDL_SetVideoMode", referenced from:
      Window::startWindow() in Window.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/testProgramError 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
```

I'm using netbeans on mac-OSX(not Xcode because you can't make cross platform apps).

Comment: "not Xcode because you can't make cross platform apps" Actually you can.

Comment: You can? I though you could only make mac apps only.

Comment: That's not true. Although it's *targeted* at iOS and OS X development, it certainly doesn't prevent you from cross-platform development.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using osx so it may be different. But for linux, we need to add `` `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` `` to the parameters of the linker.

Answer (score 1):

Link the SDL library with `-lSDL`

Alternatively try `sdl-config -- cflags --libs`, at least, it's like that with SDL2 (except using sdl2-config).

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time trying to get SDL2 to work in Xcode. Try using Eclipse with the C++ plugin, installing SDL2 with MacPorts, setting the C++ Compiler to Include "/opt/local/include/SDL2", and setting the Library path to "/opt/local/lib" and the Library to "SDL2". I'm on OSX Sierra so SDL downloads to a different path than earlier versions like Mavericks. You can find the patch with the terminal commands "sdl2-config --cflags" for the header files and "sdl2-config --libs" for the libraries. I don't like hacking the core files of a library so I don't mess with stuff like the makefile. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following flag to your compilation command:

```
-framework SDL
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify the entire path on MacOS:

```
g++ ship.cpp -o ship -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -framework SDL2
```

And the header has to be included like:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

Comment: file not found on Mac OS Ventura

Comment: Which file? The .cpp's above are just an example.